Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'ApplicationDbContext' While trying to create migrations npgsql
I've been trying to switch SQL Server to PostgreSQL but I couldn't handle it. I'm following clean architecture.
This is the first error that I encountered:

AletheiaSoft.Infrastructure.Data.ApplicationDbContextInitialiser[0] An error occurred while initialising the database.
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.Mapping.NpgsqlBigIntegerTypeMapping' threw an exception

Then I realized this is because of migrations. I just disable migrating and seeding so only thing that working was connecting. But afterwards I just got this error:

Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time

That was all error message.
Dependency injection:
using AletheiaSoft.Application.Common.Interfaces;
using AletheiaSoft.Domain.Constants;
using AletheiaSoft.Infrastructure.Data;
using AletheiaSoft.Infrastructure.Data.Interceptors;
using AletheiaSoft.Infrastructure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreSqlConnection");

        Guard.Against.Null(connectionString, message: "Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

        services.AddScoped<ISaveChangesInterceptor, AuditableEntityInterceptor>();
        services.AddScoped<ISaveChangesInterceptor, DispatchDomainEventsInterceptor>();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((sp, options) =>
        {
            options.AddInterceptors(sp.GetServices<ISaveChangesInterceptor>());

            options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
        });

        services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>());

        services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContextInitialiser>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);

        services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();

        services
            .AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddApiEndpoints();

        services.AddSingleton(TimeProvider.System);
        services.AddTransient<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.CanPurge, policy => policy.RequireRole(Roles.Administrator)));

        return services;
    }
}

DbContext:
using System.Reflection;
using AletheiaSoft.Application.Common.Interfaces;
using AletheiaSoft.Domain.Entities;
using AletheiaSoft.Infrastructure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace AletheiaSoft.Infrastructure.Data;

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<TodoList> TodoLists => Set<TodoList>();
    
    public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems => Set<TodoItem>();
    public DbSet<Client> Clients => Set<Client>();
    public DbSet<Project> Projects => Set<Project>();
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}

My stack is :

Dotnet 8.0
PostgreSql : 8.0

I tried it with SQL Server package (just to test DbContext).
SQL Server could handle with it. Also connection string of Postgresql is correct.

Please double check connection string in appsettings.json is correct and the Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL package is installed.
Create a design-time DbContext factory by implementing IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> to assist with migrations and database updates.
Ensure your Program.cs correctly configures the DbContext with dependency injection, explicitly specifying the use of PostgreSQL.
Additionally, verify compatibility between your PostgreSQL version and the Npgsql package, and ensure that your PostgreSQL server is running and accessible.

Also ensure the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design package is installed in your project as well.
